# Prove that in every tree on $n$ vertices there are at most ${n-2\over 3}$ vertices of degree more than three.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, trees

I'm trying to show that:

> If $T$ is a tree on $n$ vertices, then there are at most ${n-2\over 3}$ vertices that have a degree greater than three.

I've been unable to come up with anything so far that could be insightful or helpful. Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Note  that  a tree on $n$ vertices has $n-1$ edges and therefore
$$\sum_{v\in V}\text{deg}(v)=2(n-1).$$
Let $a$ the number of vertices of degree greater than $3$, then
$$4a+(n-a)\leq \sum_{v\in V}\text{deg}(v)=2(n-1).$$
which implies 
$$a\leq \frac{n-2}{3}.$$
This approach can be easily generalized: if $a_d$ is the number of vertices of degree greater than $d\geq 1$ then
$$a_d\leq \frac{n-2}{d}.$$

Answer (score 0):

**PS**: I have misread the question, my answer regards the case for vertices of degree greater or equal ($\geq$ ) $3$ and not $>3$:

First of all your formula is wrong, it should be $\frac{n-2}{2}$, e.g. take the 3-star (4 vertices all connected to the center).

To the proof:
Try to show it with induction: $n=1,2$ should be clear.
For bigger $n$ leave out a leave. This will yield a tree of lower degree. If you decrease the number of vertices of degree greater than 3, you now have a vertex of degree 2 (adjacent to the former leave). But you can now ignore this vertex also (by merging the to adjacent edges) and get a tree with 2 less vertices and the same amount of vertices of degree $\geq 3$. Apply now induction.

Comment: OP is asking about vertices that have degree $>3$ (not $\geq 3$).

Comment: @RobertZ: Ah, my bad. I have misread the question... My approach seems not to generalize to his case then. I would keep it here, since it doesn't use your Lemma and (hopefully) teaches OP some of ways to work with trees. If you think it's superfluous, feel free to delete it (should be possible with >50k points?).

Comment: Note that, following my approach, if we replace $4a$ with $3a$, we find your upper bound $\frac{n-2}{2}$.

Comment: @RobertZ Yes, this is clear, it also works for every degree and is in this hindsight more general. I was not referring to the statement but of the way to get there. Since OP seems to be an undergrad(?) learning how to do things should be more important than the things themself. E.g. OP should now be able to show similar formulas for any given degree using your approach and not just remember the statement.